# After phone reset - how to download all my apps from google play store?

Tags: google-play-store, factory-reset

In the web front end all my apps are still there and I added the google account in my phone. Now how do I get the apps down to the phone?

Comment: download them all again

Comment: how? i have them all marked as installed in google play store. uninstall and install them?

Comment: pressing install on each, got it. thx

Comment: Feel free to add it as an answer (with a few more words ;), so this question does not show as "unanswered" anymore :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed them all again. While google play knew my apps, it did not automatically install them again. So pressing install on every app brought them back.

About backup, I found that the android sdk has a backup function that backups everything, installed apps as well, next them I use that, maybe this makes reinstallation of apps unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Just press down on the app in your list. It will select, then click on all you want reinstalled.  Then  click install once.

You will have to click accept repeatedly.  It's easy: same spot, just tap tap tap...

Comment: Hi Richard, you are always able to edit answers instead adding new ones, please delete the other one.